# dynamic load balancing with MPI

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

In openMP, I use dynamic schedule to dynamically balance the load on the workers. Something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,chunk) private(i)
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    //loop code here
}
```

Is there a way to implement dynamic load balancing in MPI ?

Comment: dynamic load balancing of what? Could you give a relevant example of a MPI code you want to balance?

Comment: MPI doesn't include such a mechanism, since, at it's core, it's really only a tool for *communication* in parallel computations. You'd typically use a library for that, such as [Zoltan](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/zoltan/).

Comment: With MPI, dynamic load balancing can be implemented manually. For example, you can distribute work by chunks to ranks and then check if each rank has done its processing and give it another chunk by the master rank.